# Same as i++ but for more complex operation

Tags: c

*I'm not facing any problem. This question is just about C language*

Let's say I have a function like:

```
int func()
{
    static int i = 1;
    return(i++);
}
```

Now, instead of doing `i++` (`i+=1`) I'd like to do `i *= 42;` but still return the value before the multiplication.
I'm wondering if there is a way to do it the same way that `i++` works (in one expression, take value of `i` and then do `i *= 42`).

Comment: Does: `return (i *= 42) / 42;` count? It is neither elegant nor efficient, but does meet the letter of your requirements.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If `i * 42` is of a signed type (as it is in the question) and it overflows, then the behavior is undefined -- in practice dividing the result by `42` is unlikely to yield the original value. If `i` is of unsigned type and `i * 42` wraps around, the behavior is well defined, but the result of dividing by `42` definitely won't be the original value.

Comment: @KeithThompson: if `i *= 42` overflows on signed types, all bets are off before you start dividing.  You're right that with unsigned arithmetic, multiply can overflow and it is defined and division will not yield the original answer.  The only way to achieve it fully accurately is with a variable of some sort to preserve the before value, as in BLUEPIXY's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postfix `++` and `--` are the only C operators that modify an object and yield that object's previous value. If you want to do that for anything other than incrementing or decrementing by 1, you'll have to store the previous value in a temporary.

If you wanted to design your own language, you could implement a "reverse comma" operator that yields its left operand rather than its right operand. (The existing comma operator evaluates its left operand, then evaluates its right operand, then yields the value of the right operand.)

For example, if the "reverse comma" were spelled `,,`, you could do:

```
return i ,, i *= 42; /* THIS IS NOT C */
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int func()
{
    static int i = 1;
    int tmp = i;
    i *= 42;
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: I'm searching for a different way to do it, without intermediate value, replicating the idea of i++

Comment: @IggY There is no such thing as that.

Comment: @IggY: I second BLUEPIXY in that conclusion.  What he's shown is as near as you can get in C.  By all means go and design and implement your own language with the 'post-multiply' feature, but C dropped the `=*` operator many years ago because it leads to syntactic ambiguity.  Note that the old `=*` operator was identical in function to the modern `*=` operator.

Comment: Hasn't BLUEPIXY posted the answer?  It might need a little bit of explanation, but the answer is here.

Comment: You could wrap it up in a function that does `*=` and returns the previous value

Comment: It seems that it is not the desire of the OP probably.

Answer (score 0):

An assignment is an expression is C. So you could code

```
int func() {
 static int i = 1;
 return(i *= 42);
}
```

Of course if you wanted to return `i` before multiplying it you need another variable.

Comment: It would then start at 42, not at 1

Comment: That gives the result of the multiplication, but the increment is a post-increment so the returned value is the value before the operation.  I think that is what is wanted.

Comment: no, foe example return i+=1; instead of return i++; would cause the first value to be 2 instead of 1

Comment: OP: *in one expression, take value of `i` **and then do `i *= 42`***

Comment: @ta.speot.is: how would you do that?